# Setting the cursor position after setting a new delta in Quill

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying insert a new sentence to a Quill's delta when an edit is made to the Quill, all the while retaining the position of the user's cursor. When an edit is made I retrieve the cursor index from `quill.getSelection().index`, and then after applying the new delta using `quill.setContents()` I attempted to set the cursor index back to it's previous position using `quill.setSelection()`. This causes Quill to throw a "*The given range isn't in document*" error. Even trying to use `quill.setSelection()` before touching the delta inside the editor change event does not work (nothing happens). Why is `setSelection` not working as expected?

Here's a JSFiddle showcasing my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/nadavrt/gaLareyw/15/

Try editing the Quill editor text to see the issue. You can set `withInsert` to `false` to see how `setSelection` doesn't work even without an insert.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in the first case(inserting a sentence at the end of the editor) you don't need to change selection programmatically, you can just use Quill's `insertText` method:

```js
quill.insertText(quill.getLength(), "A new sentence has appeared.")
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jaimies/r4ksnma8/29/

The second case(changing cursor position when the user types) is, however, trickier. I've discovered that changing selection just after the user has typed a character is not possible with Quill. The workaround is to wrap `setSelection` call into a `setTimeout` with a timeout of 0:

```js
setTimeout(() => quill.setSelection(quill.getSelection().index + 10, 0), 0)
```

The reason this works is that the code inside of `setTimeout` is not executed immediately, even if the timeout is actually 0. By the way, you may also omit the last parameter of `setTimeout` as it is set to 0 by default

This solution is not perfect and the cursor may sometimes flicker, but that's the only way of solving this problem I've found so far.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jaimies/9h3uqktL/3/

Comment: Thanks, setTimeout does the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying insert a new sentence to a Quill's delta when an edit is made to the Quill, all the while retaining the position of the user's cursor.

I recommend using `quill.updateContents()` and constructing a new Delta as opposed to using `quill.getContents()` and `quill.setContents()`.

```
quill.updateContents(new Delta()
  .retain(quill.getSelection().index)
  .insert('A new sentence has appeared.')
);
```

Comment: Your example is taken verbatim from the Quill docs. I don't have a Delta class in my code nor do I know where it originated from. Can you please adjust your example to work with my JSFiddle?

Comment: This answer is spot on explaining setting the cursor position after setting a new delta in Quill. Thank you. The trick was `.retain`